# Calling NSException.raise() in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to raise an exception in Swift by calling NSException.raise(). The definition is:

```
class func raise(_ name: String!, format format: String!, arguments argList: CVaListPointer)
```

But when I try something like the following:

```
NSException.raise("Exception", format:"Error: %@", arguments:getVaList([error]))
```

I get the compile error: Extra argument 'format' in call.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm using XCode 6 Beta 5.

Comment: Note: Exceptions are not supported in Objective-C other than fr non-recoverably programming errors. This affects Swift code that use the Objective-C APIs.

Comment: That's what I'm using them for. If there is a fatal error I want the app to die rather than continuing in a half working state. The sooner I know about the error the better.

Comment: The format and arguments are only used to construct a string, which is passed as the "reason" argument to `init(name:reason:userInfo:)`. It would be much simpler for you to create an exception using `NSException(name:reason:userInfo:)`, passing in a reason string constructed in your own way, and then call `.raise()` on it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem seems to have been that I didn't treat the error as an optional. The following works:

```
var error: NSError?
NSException.raise("Exception", format:"Error: %@", arguments:getVaList([error!]))
```

Or you could do the following in case error is nil:

```
NSException.raise("Exception", format:"Error: %@", arguments:getVaList([error ?? "nil"]))
```

Comment: `error != nil ? error! : "nil"` can be written as `error ?? "nil"`. But closer to the original behavior would be `error ?? (nil as COpaquePointer)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @newacct, I've updated my answer to include the nil coalescing operator.

Answer (score 20):

```
var e = NSException(name:"name", reason:"reason", userInfo:["key":"value"])
e.raise()
```

Or:

```
var e = NSException(name:"name", reason:"reason", userInfo:nil)
e.raise()
```

Or:

```
NSException(name:"name", reason:"reason", userInfo:nil).raise()
```

Comment: How would you output an expression like: error ?? "nil" in an interpolated string, i.e. reason: "Error: \(error ?? \"nil\")"

Comment: @MarkHorgan Create the string in a stament and pass that to `NSException` as the reason.

Comment: @zaph In your third example, you should delete `var e = ` (I think that's just a copy-paste error.) `e` would be assigned the return value of `raise()`, which is `Void`.

Answer (score 2):

As the questioner discovered, the issue is that an optional object does not conform to `CVarArgType`, and a non-optional object does, so you need to do some kind of unwrapping.

If we look at the types that conform to `CVarArgType`, they include primitive numeric types, `COpaquePointer`, and `NSObject` has an extension that makes `NSObject` conform to it. Unfortunately, that's a direct `NSObject`, not `NSObject?`, and not `AnyObject?` as we might want. So if you have an `NSObject?`, you could unwrap it with `!`, but then if it's `nil`, it'll crash. Or if you have an object that is not a subtype of `NSObject`, then you also cannot use this.

But in C/Objective-C, you could pass any pointer type as a vararg, including any object pointer, and it worked no matter if it was a null pointer or not. How do we replicate this behavior in Swift?

By the way, they couldn't make `AnyObject?` (i.e. `Optional<AnyObject>`) conform to `CVarArgType`, because you cannot define a method (whether in the class directly, or an extension) for a specific type argument of a generic type (like "template specialization" in C++). Perhaps Apple will add it in the future. But right now a method of `Optional` must work for all type arguments. But we don't want to be able to pass non-object optionals as var args, so that doesn't work.

However, we can make a function that converts optional objects to `CVarArgType`. We can take advantage of `NSObject`'s conformance, and handle the case it doesn't handle -- `nil`. `nil` is just a null pointer, and we can instead pass a different kind of null pointer, a `COpaquePointer` null pointer, and it will work since all null pointers are the same at runtime:

```
import Foundation
func nsObjectToVarArg(obj: NSObject?) -> CVarArgType {
  return obj ?? (nil as COpaquePointer)
}
```

What about for objects that are not (or we don't know are) subtypes of `NSObject`? I made a version that is however more sketchy:

```
func anyObjectToVarArg(obj: AnyObject?) -> CVarArgType {
  return (obj != nil) ?
    Unmanaged<AnyObject>.passUnretained(obj!).toOpaque() :
    (nil as COpaquePointer)
}
```