# Manually throw exception instead of returning value in Swift

Tags: swift, exception

```
func head<T>(xs: [T]) -> T {
    if (xs.count > 0) {
        return xs.first!
    } else {
        NSException(name:"empty list", reason:"empty list", userInfo:nil).raise()
    }
}
```

This code does not compile (compiler is expecting every branch to have a return statement and does not recognize NSException as control statement).

**How can I change my code to make it compile?**

P.S. I don't want to change return value to Optional

Comment: One of the gurus explained it in an answer on SO. `fatalError` has some wizardry inside that tells the compiler it will never return so the compiler stops complaining. Just cmd-click on it and you see the `@noreturn` in front of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed `fatalError("")`

```
func head<T>(xs: [T]) -> T {
    if (xs.count > 0) {
        return xs.first!
    } else {
        fatalError("list is empty")
    }
}
```

this code works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could you reformat your NSException to something that does compile?

Try the answer for this question: [Calling NSException.raise() in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185534/calling-nsexception-raise-in-swift)